# Cannot connect to the MySQL remote server. Debian 8

Tags: mysql, debian, iptables, firewall, ovh

I have issue that I cannot reach the 3306 port (mysql) even if I set it in `iptables`.
How can I resolve this issue?

```
root@vps191532:# iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Thu Oct 22 20:42:38 2015
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [695:36753]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [469:37083]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 3306 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Oct 22 20:42:38 2015


root@vps191532:# netstat -lnpa | grep mysql
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8960/mysqld
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     42152    8960/mysqld         /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock


C:\Users>telnet 149.XXX.51.XXX 3306
Connecting To 149.XXX.51.XXX...Could not open connection to the host, on port 3306: Connect failed

root@vps191532:# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:mysql state NEW,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:mysql state ESTABLISHED
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your MySQL install is listening only for connections on the 127.0.0.1 address (also known as a very cozy place called localhost). Basically, just edit the /etc/mysql/my.cnf file and find the line:

`bind-address = 127.0.0.1`

Just change it to:

`bind-address = 0.0.0.0`

And restart your MySQL service with:

`service mysql restart`

Just remember that MySQL will start listening in all addresses, so just adjust it to suit your needs, and add firewall rules to block unwanted requests...

Cya!

Comment: Thanks! Is it safe to open the MySQL for remote connection? Or it is better to use any MySQL web tool for example phpmyadmin etc.?

Comment: Not really. You have two possible approaches: 1) Open it to direct connections from everywhere or; 2) Install phpMyAdmin to manage it remotely. In the first scenario, you'll have the advantage of connect a application directly to the MySQL server, but you're gonna have to create firewall rules to control which host can connect to it.

I guess the second one is more your case, right?